# Execute Cucumber scenario multiple times with same set of data

Tags: automated-tests, cucumber, cucumber-java

I am trying to run same scenario like around 200 times with same set of data. Dont want to use Scenario Outline with Examples. Do we have any other option?

Comment: Is there a particular reason why you don't want to use scenario outline?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this scenario...

```
Scenario: Run test in a loop
Given I want to run the following test
  | value1 | value2 | 200
```

Then in the code...

```
@When("I want to run the following test$")
public void runTestInALoop(DataTable table) {
  List<List<String>> rows = table.asLists(String.class);
  List<String> cols = rows.get(0);
  int count = Integer.valueOf(cols.get(2));

  for (int i = 0; i < count; i++) {
    // MY TEST CODE HERE
  }
}
```

There might be other ways, but this is simple enough.

Comment: Thanks for the input, What if i have multiple steps in a scenario?

Comment: @SandeepP This is why I asked in the comments section why not use scenario outline? You are basically ditching the structure that was designed for this purpose and putting something less effective in its place. If more steps are required, you will need to call them all from inside the loop.  Meaning you'll need a step definition that will call all the steps that need to.be called. Essentially, you'll be reinventing the wheel because you'll be creating a poor scenario outline.